# Integration of Legendre Polynomials with Dirac Delta function

Tags: definite-integrals, dirac-delta, legendre-polynomials

The integral I need to solve is:

$$\int^{\pi}_{0} P_{l}(\cos(\theta))\delta(\theta-\frac{\pi}{2})\sin(\theta)d\theta.$$

where $\theta$ is the angle between $z$-axis and $x-y$ plane. Since I don't know the values of $l$, I thought this integral could be written as

$$\int^{1}_{-1} P_{l}(\cos(\theta))\delta(\cos(\theta))d(\cos(\theta))$$

Am I correct ? If yes, how can I evaluate the latter ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\pi} f(\theta) \, \delta\left(\theta - \frac{\pi}{2}\right) \, d\theta &= f\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) \\
P_{2n}(0) &= \frac{(-1)^{n} \, \Gamma\left(n + \frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi} \, n!} \\
P_{2n+1}(0) &= 0
\end{align} 
then
$$\int^{\pi}_{0} P_{n}(\cos(\theta))\delta(\theta-\frac{\pi}{2})\sin(\theta)d\theta = P_{n}\left(\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right) \, \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = P_{n}(0)$$
and leads to
\begin{align}
\int^{\pi}_{0} P_{2n}(\cos(\theta))\delta(\theta-\frac{\pi}{2})\sin(\theta)d\theta &= \frac{(-1)^{n} \, \Gamma\left(n + \frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi} \, n!} \\
\int^{\pi}_{0} P_{2n+1}(\cos(\theta))\delta(\theta-\frac{\pi}{2})\sin(\theta)d\theta &= 0.
\end{align}